# Postgres JSONB query about nested/recursive elements

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a nested and hierarchical structure expressed in **JSON** e.g.:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "children": [
      { "id":2 },
      { "id": 3, "children": [
         { "id": 4 }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Can **postgres** answer a query whether the record contains `"id": 4` in any part of the document?

If yes, are such queries backed by **JSONB** indexing added in *version 9.4*?

Comment: Sadly, I tried tackling this problem with 9.3, however I ran into issues with getting the same code to run on objects and arrays. I actually think this might be a lot easier in 9.4. I started writing a recursive query to get it done, but alas, I've failed-- for today anyway.

Comment: Well nevermind, I figured out a hack to detect whether a json field was an array or object based on the first character of its textual representation.

Comment: May not directly answer your question, but I use JSONSelect and PLV8 to handle my more complex JSON traversal and querying tasks.  Took some time to get set up, but it's working well for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Thanks to therealgaxbo on reddit, we started with my original code and developed something more concise:

```
with recursive deconstruct (jsonlevel) as(
    values ('{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2},{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4}]}]}'::json)

    union all

    select 
        case left(jsonlevel::text, 1)
            when '{' then (json_each(jsonlevel)).value
            when '[' then json_array_elements(jsonlevel)
        end as jsonlevel
    from
        deconstruct
    where
        left(jsonlevel::text, 1) in ('{', '[')
)
select * from deconstruct where case when left(jsonlevel::text, 1) = '{' then jsonlevel->>'id' = '4' else false end;
```

My original response below:

I experimented like crazy and finally came up with something like this:

```
with recursive ret(jsondata) as
(select row_to_json(col)::text jsondata from 
json_each('{
   "id":1,
   "children": [
      { "id":2 },
      { "id": 3, "children": [
         { "id": 4 }
         ]
      }
   ]
}'::json) col
union 
select case when left(jsondata::text,1)='[' then row_to_json(json_each(json_array_elements(jsondata)))::text
when left((jsondata->>'value'),2)='{}' then null::text
when left((jsondata->>'value')::text,1)='[' then row_to_json(json_each(json_array_elements(jsondata->'value')))::text
else  ('{"key":'||(jsondata->'key')||', "value":'||(jsondata->'value')||'}')::json::text end jsondata 
from (
select row_to_json(json_each(ret.jsondata::json)) jsondata
from ret) xyz

)
select max(1) from ret
where jsondata::json->>'key'='id' 
and jsondata::json->>'value'='1'
```

Comment: please feel free to edit this, I'd actually like to see improvements done, or for you to at least point out any errors when you throw a ton of varying data at it.

Comment: Thank you Joe for your code. To be honest your SQL just confirmed my concerns - it is much too complex for me to justify it - I don't want everyone in the team to become Postgres guru in order to understand what's going on. I guess I have two options: flatten my JSON hierarchy to a simple list with ParentID or just forget about doing this in Postgres and query things on application level.

Comment: With 9.4 and jsonb, it'll be a lot easier.. now, you could easily write a function to hide some of the complexity if needed.

Comment: Also, if you're willing to install the V8 language, it has the power of javascript, which is even more JSON capable.